# How to display a grid(created by numpy array) by using qpixmap pyqt

Tags: python, numpy, pyqt, qpixmap

[image: That's the generated 8*8 grid.]

I used numpy to create the grid and filled cols, rows and center. How do I display this grid with QPixmap?

My code:

```
class GridTest(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GridTest, self).__init__(parent)

        self.makeGrid = QLabel("Ground Truth")


        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.makeGrid)
        self.setLayout(layout)


    def fill_square(self):
        # Parameters
        jpg_offset_row = 3
        jpg_offset_col = 6

        step = 10
        out_size = 400

        line_color = (0, 255, 255)
        center_color = (0, 0, 255)

        # Initialize white background
        grid = np.ones((step*8+9, step*8+9, 3), np.uint8)*255

        # Create the grid
        for idx in range(9):
            ctr = (step+1)*idx
            grid[:, ctr] = 0
            grid[ctr, :] = 0

        for col in range(8):
                left_x = (step + 1) * col + 1
                right_x = (step + 1) * (col + 1) - 1
                top_y = (step + 1) * jpg_offset_row + 1
                bottom_y = (step + 1) * (jpg_offset_row + 1) - 1

                corners = np.asarray(
                [(left_x, top_y),
                (right_x, top_y),
                (right_x, bottom_y),
                (left_x, bottom_y)]
                )

                cv2.fillConvexPoly(grid, corners, line_color)

        for row in range(8):
                left_x = (step + 1) * jpg_offset_col + 1
                right_x = (step + 1) * (jpg_offset_col + 1) - 1
                top_y = (step + 1) * row + 1
                bottom_y = (step + 1) * (row + 1) - 1

                corners = np.asarray(
                        [(left_x, top_y),
                        (right_x, top_y),
                        (right_x, bottom_y),
                        (left_x, bottom_y)]
                )


                cv2.fillConvexPoly(grid, corners, line_color)

        left_x2 = (step + 1) * jpg_offset_col + 1
        right_x2 = (step + 1) * (jpg_offset_col + 1) - 1
        top_y2 = (step + 1) * jpg_offset_row + 1
        bottom_y2 = (step + 1) * (jpg_offset_row + 1) - 1
        corners2 = np.asarray(
                [(left_x2, top_y2),
                (right_x2, top_y2),
                (right_x2, bottom_y2),
                (left_x2, bottom_y2)]
             )

        cv2.fillConvexPoly(grid, corners2, center_color)
        grid = cv2.resize(grid, (out_size, out_size),   interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)

        new_image = Image.fromarray(grid.astype(np.uint8))
        qimage = ImageQt(new_image)

        self.makeGrid.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(qimage))
        self.makeGrid.show()


def main():
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   ex = GridTest()
   ex.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

and libs are
    import sys
    from PyQt4.QtCore import *
    from PyQt4.QtGui import *
    from PIL import Image
    import numpy as np
    from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt
    import cv2